# HttpsURLConnection Connection to a link - Response Code 403

Tags: java, response

I've this java code

```
String u = "https://test.com";
URL url = new URL(u);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String input;
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(input);
}
br.close();
```

When I connect I get response code 403.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://test.com
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at TestHTTPSProd.main(TestHTTPS.java:45)
```

If I install the certificate in Internet Explorer and open the link `https://test.com` always goes OK.

How can I solve the problem with java?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to add the certificate to the [Java KeyStore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore)

Comment: Certificate is in the keystore. I launch with java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=ws_cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -djavax.net.debug=SSL:handshake TestHTTPS. In ws_cacerts there are all certificate. Certification validation is ok. In log i see "*** Finished
verify_data:  { 43, 129, 188, 52, 73, 5, 216, 191, 231, 1, 194, 123 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 2312"

Comment: May i need some extra header?

Comment: [HTTP response code 403](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.4) means you do not have permission to view that URL.  Certificates probably are not the problem.  Make sure your URL’s path is correct.

Comment: The path is correct. If i open with browser is ok.